# 400 bad request only on port forwarded router

Tags: webserver, port, portforwarding, http-status-code-400

Recently I got a small webserver. I port forwarded the webserver's IP4V to a public static IP.
When I am connected to the port forwarded router and I go on the public IP on my browser I get the 400 Bad request Error. But when I am connected to a different network like my phone data, it works.

I port fowarded HTTP on port 80, HTTPS on port 443, and checked if they are open.

I tried connecting on different browsers as well.

Comment: What router are you using? Some routers do not support NAT loopback where you can't access your internal network via a public IP. The request will go to your router instead of your webserver. That's probably why you're getting the error. See [NAT Loopback Routers](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers)